# How to get the worker ID and time per task shown using the web interface?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, distributed, dask

I wanted to ask if there is any way in Dask to know which output is from which worker ID. I especially need to know this for analyzing my benchmark results. I want to know what percentage of my tasks is assigned to each process.
I know that it is possible to monitor this using the web interface. But the problem is that when the number of processors is too much or there are lots of tasks per worker it is really hard to get this information only from web-interface. For multiprocessing I know that we can get this info using Profiler; but is there a way to get the results being shown using the web-interface into a dictionary or list?
Does anyone has any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer

No, but you can achieve this with [scheduler plugins](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html)

#### Long Answer

You can create a plugin that performs arbitrary computations like logging whenever a task changes state.  Here is a simple plugin that prints lots of information about a task whenever it finishes computing:

```
class MyPlugin(SchedulerPlugin):
    def transition(self, key, start, finish, *args, **kwargs):
        if start == 'processing' and finish == 'memory':
            print(kwargs)

plugin = MyPlugin()
scheduler.add_plugin(plugin)
```

You'll need some way to run this code on your scheduler.  A simple way is to use the [client.run_on_scheduler](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.run_on_scheduler) method:

```
def f(dask_scheduler):
    plugin = MyPlugin()
    dask_scheduler.add_plugin(plugin)

client.run_on_scheduler(f)
```

Of course, you probably want to do something more complex than printing, but hopefully this gets you on the right track.